# Windows Update Unknown Error 80246002

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a system which has just been freshly loaded with the following:

- Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)
- Microsoft Security Essentials (4.5.216.0)
- Office Professional 2007
- UltraVNC 1.2.0.1

After loading up the software, I moved on to the process of getting the system up to date. I've gotten through several cycles of "check, apply, reboot, repeat". This includes installation of Internet Explorer 9 (IE 10/11 will not be installed due to application compatibility limitations) and Windows 7 SP1.

However, now I seem to be running into a wall. Windows update is reporting an "unknown error" with code 80246002. Just before this round, I had encountered another "unknown error" (not sure if it was the same code). To resolve the previous error, I ran the [Windows Update Troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-the-windows-update-troubleshooter) and then the next check ran fine. After that check though, and after installing the detected updates and rebooting, I've hit this error code and the Troubleshooter is not resolving the issue this time.

Problems currently being identified by the Troubleshooter are:

- Problems installing recent updates (Not fixed)
- Service registration is missing or corrupt (Fixed)

Sometimes, a reboot will fix the problem for awhile, too. However, I still haven't gotten it to go away permanently yet.

I haven't been able to find any documentation to better clarify the meaning of this error code. What should I do to further troubleshoot/fix the problem? It's especially puzzling to me since this is a *very* fresh OS installation, so there's no good reason I can think of for issues like this.

Comment: Your right, I read the statement another way, if you roll the system back does windows update work?

Comment: @Ramhound As I said in my previous comment, a reboot has apparently fixed the issue for now. If it does not recur in the near future, I'll be closing this question. Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: Seems like with the four non-answers currently on this question, many people are also experiencing this problem at the same time. I've flagged all of them as "not an answer"; could you and others also follow up on that?

Comment: If there are indeed others experiencing the same problem (I came back on too late to see any direct indicators of such, it seems), I'll leave this open. Will need to rely on others' input to determine if a future answer is acceptable though, unless I get hit with this issue again.

Comment: Looks like this is staying open on my end. Problem showed up again today.

Comment: This article might be of interest: [Tracking: Error 80246002 Windows Update Problem](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-update/tracking-error-80246002-windows-update-problem)

Comment: @and31415 The DNS thing might explain why it appears to be an intermittent problem. However (maybe I should double-check to be sure) my network already uses alternate DNS providers. Not Google's, but not the ISP's either.